# FB.getLoginStatus() callback not called when user is logged out of Facebook

Tags: facebook, authorization, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

FB.getLoginStatus() works fine if the user is logged into facebook. But, if the user is not logged into facebook, then FB.getLoginStatus() callback is not called and I am not able to handle that case in my code because I dont get a callback. I am not in sandbox mode.

I also added 'true' to force the callback eg) `FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){}, true)` . It did not help. Is this a bug? Is it fixed yet?

If not, please give a work around when user is logged out of facebook. I ma stuck with this issue for a week now.

```
function GetFBLoginStatus() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        alert("inside call back function"); 
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken; 
            alert("Connected FBID = " + uid);
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') { 
            alert("not_authorized"); 
        } else {
            alert("Not Logged into facebook");
        }
        return true;
    }, true)
}
```

Comment: function GetFBLoginStatus() { 
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            alert("inside call back function"); 
            if (response.status === 'connected')                     
            {   var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
                var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;                
                alert("Connected FBID = " + uid);
            } 
            else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') { alert("not_authorized"); } 
            else {alert("Not Logged into facebook");}
            return true;
        }, true)       
    }

Comment: I am calling the above function on the click of a link. When the user is logged into facebook and has authorized my app, I get the following alerts 1) "inside call back function" 2) "Connected FBID = XXXXX". When the user is logged into facebook, and has not authorized my app, i get the alerts 1) "inside call back function" 2) "not_authorized". But when the user is not logged into facebook, I dont get any alerts at all. ie, the call back function is not called

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can create an `auth.logout` event:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
    alert('logged out!');
});
```

Or a better solution, create an `auth.authResponseChange` event:

```
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    console.log('The status of the session changed to: '+response.status);
    alert(response.status);
});
```

**Update:**

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
        appId  : 'APP_ID',
        status : true,
        cookie : true,
        xfbml  : true,
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        alert('logged in');
    });

    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        alert('logged out');
    });     
};

function GetFBLoginStatus() {
    FB.getLoginStatus( function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
            alert(accessToken);
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
            //login function
            alert('login first');
        } else {
            //login function
            alert('login first');
        }
    }, true);
}

//Load the SDK Asynchronous
(function(d) {
    var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
    js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
    ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
} (document));
</script>

<div>
<a href="#" onclick="GetFBLoginStatus()"><img src="../FacebookSmall.bmp" />ddd</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Philip. I tried both the events, but it did not help. Not sure if I used it the right way. I added FB.Event.subscribe(); before the call to FB.getLoginStatus(). But I never got any alerts when the user logged out of facebook.

Comment: Have you try to refresh the page after you logout from Facebook? Just to see what it's doing. If it's possible share this part of your code to take a look.

Comment: I have given my code below. Please help. I am stuck with this issue.

Comment: @PiaPalackathadom, i update the code, but have in mind that we are not here to write code for you. Also you have to upvote helpful answers and comments, or select an answer as the correct one. You must read the SO FAQ: http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Philip, thanks for the updated code. It works perfectly. Thanks once again for all your help.

Comment: Glad you found a solution to your question!

Answer (score 0):

Responding to Philip's comment: I tried to refresh the page after logging out of facebook. Here is my code: I am calling the javascript function GetFBLoginStatus() on the click of a link. When I am logged into facebook everything works fine. When I am not logged into facebook, I don't get any alerts.

```
<div id="fb-root">
</div>

<!-- pull down Facebook's Javascript SDK -->
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>

<script>
    // initialize the library with your Facebook API key
    FB.init({ apiKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXX' });
</script>

<div>
<a href="#" onclick="GetFBLoginStatus()"><img src="../FacebookSmall.bmp" /></a>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function GetFBLoginStatus() 
{
          FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response){                 
        alert(response.status);
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) 
{
         alert("inside call back function");

        if (response.status === 'connected')                     
        {   
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
           var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;                
           alert("Connected FBID = " + uid);
        } 
        else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') 
 { 
   alert("not_authorized"); 
 } 
       else 
{
  alert("Not Logged into facebook");    
}

     }, true) ;      
  }
```